# Can we use value in a field as title for data retrieved using as keyword?

Tags: mysql

I tried the following query..but it is not working

```
SELECT course_id as a,
       sub1 as (SELECT subj1 
                FROM   stu_subject
                WHERE  course_id = a.course_id),
       sub2 as (SELECT subj2
                FROM   stu_subject
                WHERE  course_id = a.course_id),
       sub3 as (SELECT subj3
                FROM   stu_subject
                WHERE  course_id = a.course_id) 
FROM   stu_mark_list
WHERE  course_id=(SELECT course_id 
                  FROM   stu_mark_list
                  WHERE  course_id = a.course_id)
```

Comment: Are you trying reverse engineering?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?
Your sub query (inline) should come first then you need to write allies "as"

```
SELECT course_id as a
,(SELECT subj1 FROM stu_subject WHERE course_id=a.course_id) as sub1 
,(SELECT subj2 FROM stu_subject WHERE course_id=a.course_id) as sub2
,(SELECT subj3 FROM stu_subject WHERE course_id=a.course_id) sub3 
FROM stu_mark_list where course_id=(SELECT course_id FROM stu_mark_list WHERE course_id=a.course_id)
```

Example : select col1, (select top 1 abc from myTable) as col2 from SomeTable.
In above example value is taken from MyTable and name is given as col2.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually I want to use subj1 from table stu_subject as title

Comment: so instead of "as sub1" write "as subj1".